# Linear Regression: intercept over coefficient, why

Tags: algorithms, linear-regression, data-analysis

Question Edited to add more information

I have come across a formula that uses the calculated values from a linear regression,

but I am not sure on how it is useful

lets say for example I have

```
x = [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]

y = [ 1  2  7  28  6  6  5  27  4  2  6  12]
```

this gets me an intercept of 7.37 and a coefficient of 0.22

so the linear regression formula is Y = a + b*x

b is the coefficient
a is the intercept

```
Y = 7.37 + 0.22*x
```

the formula is

if b is greater than 0

```
number = ((K_max-a)/(b) - last x)
```

if b is lower than 0

```
number = ((K_min-a)/(b) - last x)
```

where

k_max and k_min =  are values defined before the calculation
for the example

k_max = 25

k_min = 5

last x = is the last value of x, in this case 12

what does this intercept divided in the coefficient means? what does it tells me about my data set?

please let me know if this makes sense, or if this has been used elsewhere

thank you

Comment: What is b in your formula? Also, please use MathJax, here is an intro: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess...

Assuming the linear model is $y=a+bx$, if we let $y=k$ and solve for $x$, we get $\displaystyle x_k=\frac{k-a}{b}$ , in which case, we could interpret $\displaystyle x_k-x_n=\frac{k-a}{b}-x_{n}$ (where $x_n$ is the "last" $x$ value) as the distance along the $x$ axis we must traverse from $x_n$ until the value of the prediction is $k$. This also might be why $k$ is termed a threshold. This might be useful if we want to see how great an extrapolation is required to predict $k$, for example.

Comment: @JoseFernandoGomezDavila I think the interpretation still holds. Could you edit your initial post with more complete information about the question? Given your data, there is only one value for the coefficient possible. Is the question maybe about a confidence interval about $b$?